# Why is gson library setting integer values to zero when converting json response to ArrayList<Object>?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm trying to convert a json format response from a web service into an `ArrayList<Stop>` object.

Before converting the json response into a java object I made sure the database is retreiving all the data in a proper manner, see the image below.

[image]

However after converting the json response and debugging the android app I realized that the value of all the integer fields has been set to zero. 
The fields `stopId` and `journeyId` correspond to a `PRIMARY_KEY` and  `FOREIGN_KEY` respectively in the database.

[image]

This is the snipet of code I wrote to do this. 
[image]

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Serialize name is not match. Look at json key naming, you write as stopId whereas in your model `Stop` class you write stop_id, if you want to use different name for your variable in your `Stop` class use `@SerialzeName("key")` and then below it's declare the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your model class according `Camel Case Sensitive,` change `stop_id` to `stopId` and `journey_id` to `journeyId`. Or configure your Gson according your necessities:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).create();
String jsonRepresentation = gson.toJson(someObject);
System.out.println(jsonRepresentation);
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. The first solution worked for me. Didn't try the second one but I guess it's valid too.